# Работа с Bitmap

Tags: android

Нашел статью, где рассказывается, что можно сжать размер картинки используя Bitmap и избежать ошибку OutOfMemory. Там показывают, как они берут те самые картинки с SD-карты, а мне нужно чтобы картинки брались с ресурсов. Как мне это сделать?

http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/372-urok-160-risovanie-bitmap-chtenie-izobrazhenij-bolshogo-razmera.html

Comment: Мне кажется название не совсем соответствует вопросу

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Гуглим : android get bitmap from resources. Видим правильный ответ

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.image);
```

Из вашего примера замените эти строчки:

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"map.jpg");
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: @user207012, если ответ решет вашу задачу, то вы можете отметить его верным, нажав на галочку слева от тела ответа.

Comment: Не могу, низкая репутация.